# heap allocating address in the high memory range

Tags: c, malloc

I am facing this strange issue in which the addresses `malloc`'ed between two calls to `malloc` differ a lot in terms of the address allocated, for example:

```
iovec = 0x6201f0
```

and:

```
iovec = 0x7ffff00008e0
```

and the size of the `iovec` structure is 40 bytes. Is there a possible reason to explain this behavior ?

Comment: Show us how you print them.

Comment: On Mac OS X, sometimes the first allocation of memory can be at a noticably different address than the second, even allowing for the size of the previously allocated chunk (though it isn't as dramatic a difference as you're showing).  That's a property of the memory allocation system.  Is there a reason it is a problem?  As long as the system returns valid addresses, you have no obvious cause for complaint or concern.

Comment: printf(" iovec = %p size = %d\n", iovec, sizeof(iovector_t));
after first malloc :-
iovec = 0x6201f0 size = 40
after second malloc :-
iovec = 0x7ffff00008e0 size = 40

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the address, it should not be an issue. One potential reason is that there are two different routes for the dynamic memory system to get memory from the system. One is `brk()` and the other anonymous (i.e. `MAP_ANON`) `mmap()`. I believe `glibc` uses `brk()` for small amounts of memory but `mmap()` for large. If you have an intervening call to allocate a large amount of memory, the subsequent `malloc()` for a 40 byte `iovec` may sit in the end of the page(s) grabbed using `mmap()`. If you really want to know what's happening, I suggest you use `strace` and find out the memory addresses returned.

Also note that if you allocated one on the stack rather than the heap, then it will (of course) have a different looking memory address.